# How can use one ssh for two commands to save 2 different files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ssh

How can use one ssh for two commands to save 2 different files. Like one command is `ps -ef | grep Consumer | cut -f6 -d' '` and save this output in file.log, second command is `ps -ef | grep Test | cut -f7 -d' '` and save output in test.log

Comment: The output files are supposed to be on local system, or remote (ssh'ed)?

Comment: output on local system

Comment: I presume, that `ps -ef` needs to be run on the remote system.

Comment: Yes . ps -ef needs to be run on the remote system but output should save on local system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only `ps -ef` needs to be run on the remote system. Parsing the output can happen at local system.

& It's easier with `awk`. Needs just single ssh session & `ps -ef` command snapshot:

```
ssh user@host ps -ef | awk -F' ' '/Consumer/{print $6 > "file.log"}; /Test/{print $7 > "test.log"}'
```

1. `grep+cut` can happen within `awk` - `'/pattern/{print $n}'`
2. File redirection can also happen easily with `awk`. Check the syntax in above answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather prefer to do parsing on remote system only as ps -ef gives a big output and if we don't parse and cut it over there then entire output is transferred from remote system to local system over network. It can take more time if output size increases. And we don't even need entire output on local system too so it is better parse it on remote system only.

ssh user@host ps -ef | grep Consumer | cut -f6 -d' ' > file.log; ps -ef | grep Test | cut -f7 -d' ' > test.log